# Location Get Time return same time always

Tags: java, android

Locations method getTime() always return same time that is

> Sun Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2017

I check this method in different device and find out that in asus tablet it is returning same date . So I wonder that this issue is device specific and we have to make some changes in device setting or is there other issue that I am facing.

Comment: Read [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()) if you haven't already .

Comment: Than why in my other device it display me correct time and not fix time

Comment: Well as per documentation time should be when the location is fixed .Check Setting on Your Asus device .

Comment: location is changing because I am saving locations in my database . latitude and longitude is definitely changing but not the time .

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings --> Date & Time --> disable automatic date & time and also disable automatic time zone. Then go to select time zone option and select the Locale what you want. Thats it. Now when you access your date and time programatically, it will show depends on the Locale you selected.